# How can two squads of friends join the same DMZ instance?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

In the Call of Duty DMZ mode, you are in squads of 3 players, however it's possible to create an alliance when in game by inviting other squads to join you.

[You can invite a squad using the ping wheel.](https://www.ggrecon.com/guides/warzone-2-dmz-assimilation-how-to/)

However, when myself and 5 of my clan mates want to play in two separate squads, we cannot seem to be able to get into the same game instance.

Is there a way for us to join the same game instance? We have tried launching at the same time over and over and had no luck.

Comment: I would usually do what you did, the 'join queue at the same time' I do so in apex sometimes and it does work. But if it doesnt, I guess CoD got wise to it and in the matchmaking algorithm they make sure you dont join anybody on your friend list. But this is very much theories.

Comment: I wondered the same as it could be considered an exploit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best luck you'd have for this is just have both groups start matchmaking at the same time. Since player counts are quite high this will probably be difficult, though.

Assimilation isn't really meant for team stacking the way you want it... it's more for like organically created alliances.

Answer (score -1):

I have done it before with a friend who lived a block away, so closer proximity,
meaning that the game tends to pair people who live in same regions together. Because it takes latency, i.e. ping into account.
If you can't understand the GEO PROXIMITY helps you match... you on wrong forum and machine... get a leap frog...

Start at exact same time, then call out the number of players needed and time left as a way to see if you actually made it into the same lobby or if you need to back out and try again.

Comment: Your answer is stating basically same thing as accepted answer.

Comment: Not really... the geo-location proximity is just as important if not more than just starting same time...

Comment: Not much. geo location is only important if they're living other continent, e. g. americas and eurasia, because their server is separated. For example, I live in Japan, and has a friend who's living in Korea, though I've managed to match him in DMZ without any problem (of course not as a party - it doesn't even took any effort, and we've managed to match thrice in a row). This is because we're both matching in Asia server. If server is same, then it shouldn't take much effort.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean in the middle part, can you rephrase it and stop using ... where it's not needed?